# Sets of finite perimeter: intersection with an half space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I have a question regarding sets of finite perimeter. In particular I'm interested to find 
$$\mu_{E \cap H_t}, \label{1}\tag{1}$$
where $E$ is a set of finite perimeter in a generic open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $H_t$ is a half-space, i.e., $H_t =\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n:x\cdot e<t \right\}$ for some $e \in S^{n-1}\mathrel{:=}\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\lvert x\rvert=1 \right\}$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
The notation $\mu_E$ means $\mu_E=\nu_E \mathcal{H}^{n-1} \mathop\lfloor \partial^* E$, where "$\lfloor$" denotes the restriction.

In the book [*Sets of finite perimeter and Geometric Variational problems*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/sets-of-finite-perimeter-and-geometric-variational-problems/F8D0DABFFFB0D444C5AD5D37B3E3DBC1) by F. Maggi ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2976521)), I found a partial answer to my question:

> **Exercise 15.3 (Intersection with half spaces)**. If $E$ is a set
>   of finite perimeter in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $E \cap H_t$ is a set of
>   finite perimeter in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and, for a.e. $t \in \mathbb{R}$,
>   $$ \mu_{E \cap H_t}=\mu_E \mathop\lfloor H_t +e \mathcal{H}^{n-1} \mathop\lfloor
>  \left( E \cap \partial H_t\right), \label{2}\tag{2}
> $$
>   where "$\lfloor$" denotes the
>   restriction and $\mu_E=\nu_E \mathcal{H}^{n-1} \mathop\lfloor \partial^* E$.

**Question I**: does \eqref{2} hold true even if $E$ is a set of finite perimeter in a generic open set $\Omega$ and not in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
If not, how I can derive \eqref{1}?

In the same book, the author gives the formula for the general intersection between two sets of finite perimeter:

> **Theorem 16.3 (Set operations on Gauss–Green measures)**. If $E$ and $F$ are two sets of finite perimeter, then
>   $$\mu_{E \cap F}=\mu_E \mathop\lfloor F^{(1)} +\mu_F \mathop\lfloor E^{(1)}+\nu_E
>  \mathcal{H}^{n-1} \mathop\lfloor \left\{ \nu_E = \nu_F \right\},\label{3}\tag{3}$$
>   where
>   $$\left\{ \nu_E = \nu_F \right\}=\left\{ x \in \partial^*E \cap
>  \partial^*F : \nu_E (x)=\nu_F (x) \right\}.$$

**Question II**: How can one deduce \eqref{2} from \eqref{3} when $F=H_t$? And why $E^{(1)}$ in \eqref{3} does not compare in \eqref{2}?

Comment: Some help or advice?

Comment: In particular does the equation (2) hold true if $E$ is a set of locally finite perimeter, i.e.$E$ has finite perimeter for every compact set $K \in \mathbb{R}^n$? Thanks.